# Prove that $e^{\lambda A}Be^{-\lambda A}=B$

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function, quantum-mechanics

> Prove that $$e^{\lambda A}Be^{-\lambda A}=B$$ if $[A,B]=0$. $A$ and $B$ are operators and $\lambda$ is a complex number.

Can anyone explain how I should go about this question? How do I calculate the exponential of an operator via matrix operations? I just need a hint. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exponential of a matrix is defined through its power series:
$\exp(A)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{A ^i}{i!}$. Clearly you would like to simplify the two exponentials, but in order to do so you need that...

Comment: Can I simply state that since A and B commute any function of A for example the exponential, also commutes with B and then use this to eliminate the exponentials and prove the statement?

Comment: Yes, you can. Of course you need to know some expression of $A$ in terms of $A$ in order to be sure that $[A,B]=0$ implies $[\exp(A),B]=0$. In this case you are using the fact that $[A,B]=0 \Rightarrow [A^n,B]=0$.